# Java : parse C source code, extract variables and methods

Tags: java, parsing

I want to parse C files to extract variables and functions.
I need to change some local variables to global type.
Is there any java library for this purpose?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Library to parse C/C++ source code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318347/library-to-parse-c-c-source-code)

Comment: not actually, i'm looking for java library.

Comment: Well, I do not think there is a library(a single JAR) - Hope you know that ANTLR is a java based solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANTLR is a great tool that has community and APIs for JAVA, C, C#, Python, ActionScript. There are ready to use grammars for many programming languages (C, C#, Java, Perl etc) or custom grammar can be created if needed.

Check grammar list [here](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/list)

Comment: As i said, i need to modify variables in some conditions. Can ANTLR help?